# Scroll 100% on mousescroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want an action to happen when a user starts scrolling. I tried to research the web for it but the only thing that is coming up is 100% scroll on CLICK :)

I want the window to be forced 100% down as soon as the user starts scrolling on mousewheel. Is this possible? :) Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried? You don't even need jquery, you could just watch verticaloffset < 0 to fire off something like `window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);`   .....however when you use a profile picture that looks like it came from a dating website you'll have guys falling over each other to do your work for you anyway so I guess it doesn't really matter... ;)

Comment: No jquery version...`window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){ window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight); });`

Answer (score 1):

First off:
The trouble with forcing the screen to scroll all the way to the bottom is that you can no longer move on screen - as **every time you scroll you reset the position.**

However, you can use `JQuery` and listen for the `scroll` event.

Something like this:

```
$(document).on('scroll', function(){
    console.log('yeah');
    // window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight); // left this commented out
});
```

You can do the same without JQuery too. Just plain old JavaScript

```
document.onscroll = function(){ 
                      console.log('oh yeah');
                      // window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight); // left this commented out
                    }
```

Comment: I want it to happen EACH time. So that you only get to see one window at the time, and if you scroll up, I want it to scroll back up a window. Thank you so much for reply! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could look into the jQuery Mousewheel plug-in:  http://plugins.jquery.com/mousewheel/

Answer (score 0):

yes, it pretty simple actually, do something like:

`$(window).bind("wheel", function (e) {
   if (e.deltaY > 0) // please just check if you should compare > 0 or < 0, i don't have a mouse here :) to check the event
      $("body").scrollTop(10e9);
});`

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this is actually what you want, because this technically checks for any scroll in the page, not the mousewheel in particular, hoping jQuery is ok.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function (event) {//Checks if scroll happens
        //set the left offset to 0, set the second one to the height of the document
        window.scroll(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
    });
});
```

Again, this is for ANY scroll movement.

Answer (score 0):

1) Add some invisible link:

```
<a id="jump-on-scroll" href="#bottom" style="color:white">...</a>
```

2) On mouse wheel:

```
$(window).bind("wheel", function (e) {
   if (e.deltaY > 0) {
     $('#jump-on-scroll').trigger('click');
   }
});
```